# how to make array like this

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array in the array, and I want to make it just one array, and I can easily retrieve that data
i have some like
[this](https://3v4l.org/uo6kZ)

but the coding only combines the last value in the first array, not all values

is it possible to make it like that? 
so that I can take arrays easily

Comment: this is not a php array. Are you need a conversion in php or js

Comment: sorry, this is my output json

Comment: what are you using JS or PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: no duplicate, this is different, and if it's the same I am still confused about applying it in my case.

this helps but only the last value joins https://3v4l.org/uo6kZ

Comment: @FutraPlayer You edited your original question, which was slightly different. Now it's an exact duplicate though. So edit it back with your actual data (simplified), because the linked question does solve your current issue.

Comment: i have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the unpacking operator `...`, combined with [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array['test2'] = array_merge(...array_merge(...$array['test2']));
```

In your case you need to flatten exactly twice, if you try to do it one time too much it will fail due to the items being actual arrays themselves (from PHP's perspective).

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/npnTi**

Comment: your answer works, but only combines the last value in the first array, not all values

Comment: @dWinder I didn't notice your answer, sorry about that. Let me upvote it at least.

Comment: @FutraPlayer You should probably accept dWinder's answer instead, who posted the same solution earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge` ([doc](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) and `...` (which break array to separate arrays):

```
function flatten($arr) {
    return array_merge(...$arr);
}

$arr = [[["AAA", "BBB"]], [["CCC"]]];
$arr = flatten(flatten($arr)); // using twice as you have double depth
```

In your case, `$arr` is `$obj["test2"]`. If your object is json cast it to array first and if it is a string use [`json_decode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/8hHWf)

Comment: @FutraPlayer updated the answer for double loop - if this helps you you may mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

if you have a array then you can use the below code

```
if(!empty($array['test2'])){
    $newarray = array();

    foreach ($array['test2'] as $arrayRow) {
        $newarray = array_merge($newarray,$arrayRow);
    }

    $array['test2'] = $newarray;
}
```